# Executable generated with pyinstaller crashes when printing special character

Tags: python, special-characters, pyinstaller

I'm using Python 3.6 and I have this code:

```
    text = "ç"
    print(text)
```

When I execute is there's no problem. When I generate an executable using pyinstaller the program executes just fine. However, when I execute the generated application the program crashes when executing. How can I prevent this?